# Add new items to a Html selectbox

Tags: jquery

Can I check for existing items in a html select box while adding them. A user types a text in a input box and then clicks button to add items. But I want to check for identical items before adding. Is there a efficient way to write this script?

Comment: I am sorry..i meant identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `$('#dropdown option[value=' + newoption + ']')` returns an option or not.

E.g.

```
if ($('#dropdown option[value=' + newoption + ']').length > 0) {
    // Option exist.
} else {
    // Option does not exist.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fix typo and shorten the logical check in js...

```
if ($("#dropdown option[value=' + newoption + ']").length) {
  // Option exist.
} else {
  // Option does not exist.
}
```

Comment: Uh, there was no means of a typo and you've now made this technically invalid. The `newoption` was supposed to be a variable.